# K8S - using Prometheus to monitor another prometheus instance in secure way

Tags: security, kubernetes, prometheus, istio, prometheus-operator

I've installed [Prometheus operator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator) `0.34` (which works as expected) on cluster **A** (main prom)
Now I want to use the [federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/) option,I mean collect metrics from other Prometheus which is located on other  K8S cluster **B**

**Secnario:**

> 1. have in cluster **A** MAIN [prometheus operator](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator) `v0.34` [config](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-operator/values.yaml)
> 2. I've in cluster **B** SLAVE [prometheus](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus) `2.13.1` [config](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus/values.yaml)

Both installed successfully via helm, I can access to localhost via `port-forwarding` and see the scraping results on each cluster.

**I did the following steps**

Use on the operator (main cluster A)  [additionalScrapeconfig](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/additional-scrape-config.md) 
I've added the following to the `values.yaml` file and update it via helm.

```
additionalScrapeConfigs:
 - job_name: 'federate'  
   honor_labels: true
   metrics_path: /federate
   params:
     match[]:
       - '{job="prometheus"}'
       - '{__name__=~"job:.*"}'
   static_configs:
     - targets:
       - 101.62.201.122:9090 # The External-IP and port from the target prometheus on Cluster B
```

I took the target like following:

on prometheus inside **cluster B** (from which I want to collect the data) I use:

`kubectl get svc -n monitoring`

And get the following entries:

Took the `EXTERNAL-IP` and put it inside the `additionalScrapeConfigs` config entry.

Now I switch to cluster `A` and run `kubectl port-forward svc/mon-prometheus-operator-prometheus  9090:9090 -n monitoring`

Open the browser with `localhost:9090` see the graph's and click on `Status` and there Click on `Targets`

And see the new target with job `federate`

[image]

Now my main question/gaps. (security & verification)

1. To be able to see that target `state` on green (see the pic) I configure the prometheus server in cluster `B` instead of using `type:NodePort` to use [`type:LoadBalacer`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus/values.yaml#L835) which expose the metrics outside, this can be good for testing but I need to **secure it**, how it can be done ?
   How to make the e2e works in **secure way**...

tls
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/1.8/configuration/configuration/#tls_config

Inside **cluster A** (main cluster) we use certificate for out services with `istio` like following which works

```
tls:
   mode: SIMPLE
   privateKey: /etc/istio/oss-tls/tls.key
   serverCertificate: /etc/istio/oss-tls/tls.crt
```

I see that inside the doc there is an option to config

```
    additionalScrapeConfigs:
     - job_name: 'federate'  
       honor_labels: true
       metrics_path: /federate
       params:
         match[]:
           - '{job="prometheus"}'
           - '{__name__=~"job:.*"}'
       static_configs:
         - targets:
           - 101.62.201.122:9090 # The External-IP and port from the target
#        tls_config:
#          ca_file: /opt/certificate-authority-data.pem
#          cert_file: /opt/client-certificate-data.pem
#          key_file: /sfp4/client-key-data.pem
#          insecure_skip_verify: true
```

But not sure which certificate I need to use inside the prometheus operator config , the certificate of the main prometheus A or the slave B?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should consider using [Additional Scrape Configuration](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/additional-scrape-config.md#additional-scrape-configuration)

> `AdditionalScrapeConfigs` allows specifying a key of a Secret
>   containing additional Prometheus scrape configurations. Scrape
>   configurations specified are appended to the configurations generated
>   by the Prometheus Operator.

2. I am affraid this is not officially supported. However, you can update your `prometheus.yml` section within the Helm chart. If you want to learn more about it, check out [this blog](https://www.promlts.com/resources/wheres-my-prometheus-yml?utm_source=sof&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=prometheus)
3. I see two options here:

> Connections to Prometheus and its exporters are not encrypted and
>   authenticated by default. [This is one way of fixing that with TLS
>   certificates and
>   stunnel](https://0x63.me/tls-between-prometheus-and-its-exporters/).

Or specify [Secrets](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/security/#secrets) which you can add to your scrape configuration.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer 1+! unfortunately im still struggling to make it work, I've put a bounty and it will be great if you can provide the steps to do it ...thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options spring to mind:

1. Put the two clusters in the same network space and put a firewall in-front of them
2. VPN tunnel between the clusters.
3. Use istio multicluster routing (but this could get complicated): https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/multicluster